# Parsing string with multiple regex's

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, token

Let's say I have two Java Patterns, one for finding whitespace at the beginning of the line, and the other for finding non-whitespace at the beginning of the line:

```
Pattern ws  = Pattern.compile("^\\s+");
Pattern nws = Pattern.compile("^\\S+");
String text = "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing.";
```

I want to loop through the text, separating it blocks of whitespace and blocks of non-whitespace, removing each token from the beginning of text:

```
while(text.length() > 0) {
    String nextToken = "";
    try {
        //TODO: detect grouping and move it to nextToken.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO: error handling
    }
    if(nextToken.length() > 0)
        _tokens.add(nextToken);
}
```

I don't just want to replace stuff. "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing." should split to ["\t", "Some", "\n\t ", "text", ...]

How would you accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and a single `Pattern` which matches either kind of token.

```
Pattern tokenPattern  = Pattern.compile("\\s+|\\S+");
String text = "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing.";
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
while (true) {
    String token = scanner.findWithinHorizon(tokenPattern, 0);
    if (token == null) break;
    tokens.add(token);
}
System.out.println(tokens);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would remove all the spaces  or non-space characters which was present at the start,

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^(?:\\s+|\\S+)", ""));
```

Comment: I don't just want to replace stuff. "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing." should split to ["\t", "Some", "\n\t ", "text", ...]

Comment: @AaronF In that case why there is "removing" in "*I want to loop through the text, **removing** blocks of whitespace and blocks of non-whitespace*"? Did you perhaps want to write "separating"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I said "removing" because I want to successively remove the blocks of characters from text. "Hello world." becomes " world" becomes "world" becomes "", and [] becomes ["Hello"] becomes ["Hello", " "] becomes ["Hello", " ", "world."]

Answer (score 1):

After your update it seems that your goal may be to separate whitespaces from non-whitespaces. In that case place on which you should split can be described by regex which will use [look-around mechanisms](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In other words regex should be matching places which have

- non-whitespace before and whitespace after it
- or whitespace before and non-whitespace character after it.

Such regex can look like `"(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)"` and you can use it in `split` method

```
String text = "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing.";
for (String s:text.split("(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)"))
    System.out.println("'"+s+"'");
```

---

On the other hand you may wan't to also use alternation operator - `OR` which is represented by `|` and `find` method from `Matcher` to iterate over text and find matching substrings.

```
String text = "\tSome \n\t text \n that needs \t parsing.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println("'"+m.group()+"'");
```

In both cases output will be

```
'   '
'Some'
' 
     '
'text'
' 
 '
'that'
' '
'needs'
'    '
'parsing.'
```

(I surrounded results with `'` to show that for instance firs result does in fact contain tabulator `\t` which is printed as `' '`)